# How to change 15% into 0.15 in Java?

Tags: java, calculator

So, I am making a basic tip calculator and I need to know how to change the users input of 15%, 23%, etc. into 0.15, 0.23, etc.

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TipCalc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner meal = new Scanner(System.in);
        double food, tax, tip, fin;
        System.out.println("How much was the meal?");
        food = meal.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How much was the tax?");
        tax = meal.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How much would you like to tip? I recomend 15%");
        tip = meal.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: `tip = meal.nextInt() / 100.0;`

Comment: The most important bug: reco**m**mend

Answer (score 4):

```
double tip;
tip = meal.nextDouble() / 100;
```

Or

```
double tip = 15.0;
tip  = tip / 100;
```

Or Even

```
double tip = 15.0;
tip /= 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input for your tip is 15.

Using

```
tip = meal.nextDouble() / 100.0;

System.out.println(tip);
```

would OUTPUT: 0.15